# How to have design a button with a rectangular top and semicircle bottom

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

Please help me to create this shape in flutter.

Comment: use CustomPaint widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is enough for you, cause it is not exactly the same

```
Container(
      width: 140,
      height: 50,
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.amber,//Use a gradient here
        shadowColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 170),
        elevation: 20.0,
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),)),
        child: InkWell(
          child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline_sharp,
                color: Colors.white,),//Change this for your icon
                Text(" My Shoppe!",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white
                  ),),//Change this for your text font
              ],
            ),),
          onTap: () {},
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

The easiest way would be making that shape on figma or photoshop, then using it as an image inside of a container, and stack the container with the text and the icon